# Maintaining Makefiles and CMakeLists.txt

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

When you're working to very big projects with a large amount of people, maintaining both `Makefiles` and `CMakeLists.txt` could be very difficult. I know that `CMakeLists.txt` could generate `Makefiles`, but suppose that I want to compile my code by using `make` and in the same time, use an IDE to have a kind of intellisense. How can I achieve it?

In the scenario that I'm describing, `CMakeLists.txt` files will disappear, so I won't have the chance to generate solutions with them.

Comment: ***How can I achieve it?*** I don't understand the problem. Get rid of the Makefiles and use `CMake` for all platforms and you don't have the issue.

Comment: I think, you are trying to shoot yourself in the leg and asking for a best advice on shotgun placement. Stick to one build system. If you are using cmake - use cmake, and if you are using gnu make - use gnu make. Don't mix and match, it will only lead to pain and suffering.

Comment: ??? Just use cmakelists

Comment: `Makefiles` are highly optimized, while `CMakeLists.txt` are not.

Comment: Optimised in what way? Google thinks they're so slow they invented a whole new build system https://ninja-build.org/

Comment: BTW, CMake has ninja support.

Comment: @AlanBirtles google thinks a lot of things. There is nothing wrong (performance-wise) with non-recursive makefiles.

Comment: CMake is not a build manager! It is a generator of files for other build managers, so you can generate project for IDEs (Visual Studio, Xcode, CodeBlocks, ..) or generate MakeFile, or whatever you prefer and CMake supports. So I do not undestund why do you maintain `CMakeLists.txt` and `Makefiles` at the same time.

Comment: @SergeyA you have to get to projects the size of chrome to notice a big difference but ninja is definitely a bit faster https://david.rothlis.net/ninja-benchmark/

Comment: Just use CMake and generate Makefiles when (if) needed. Don't maintain separate Makefiles.

Comment: @AlanBirtles You definitely don't need a project the size of Chrome to notice that ninja is *far* supperior to make. The project I work on daily is ~500k lines of C++ code and building it on a 20 core/40 threads workstation - from scratch - takes ~5min with ninja, but more than 8min with make.

Comment: If you use cmake with the unix makefile generator, you'll be able to use make normally. However, I'd suggest using ninja since makefile are generally slow

Comment: It is unclear what is exactly the situation. Why do you need to maintain both makefiles and cmakelists?

Answer (score 4):

CMake is not a build manager!
It is a generator of files for other build managers!

So you can generate project for IDEs (Visual Studio, Xcode, CodeBlocks, ..) or generate MakeFile, or whatever you prefer and CMake supports. So I do not understand why do you maintain `CMakeLists.txt` and `Makefiles` at the same time.
Just maintain `CMakeLists.txt` and then generate respective `Makefiles` from it.

For details see [CMake Documentation - generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generators.7.html):

> ### Command-Line Build Tool Generators
>
> These generators support command-line build tools. In order to use them, one must launch CMake from a command-line prompt whose environment is already configured for the chosen compiler and build tool.
>
> - [Borland Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Borland%20Makefiles.html)
> - [MSYS Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/MSYS%20Makefiles.html)
> - [MinGW Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/MinGW%20Makefiles.html)
> - [NMake Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/NMake%20Makefiles.html)
> - [NMake Makefiles JOM](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/NMake%20Makefiles%20JOM.html)
> - [Ninja](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Ninja.html)
> - [Unix Makefiles](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Unix%20Makefiles.html)
> - [Watcom WMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/generator/Watcom%20WMake.html)

Bottom line you should be able to generate files for IDE or Makefile for you favorite build manager without any complications.

> In the scenario that I'm describing, `CMakeLists.txt` files will disappear, so I won't have the chance to generate solutions with them.

WAT? You are doing something very strange and most probably wrong and you didn't provide any details abut that.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning intellisense I would say:

- Visual Studio 2017 as built-in support for CMake, [see announcement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio/)
- CMake can generate a json file with all commands see [**CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS**](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS.html)
  so you can use it to have smart [clang based completion in vim](https://bastian.rieck.ru/blog/posts/2015/ycm_cmake/)
- QtCreator as built-in support for CMake so you'll have completion too.

Answer (score 0):

Extra tip at first: Do not try to mix both handmade `make` files and `CMake` over the whole time of the project.

The normal way is to create the make files using cmake. The extra of cmake is the cross platform and in your case the **nativ** support by some IDEs, eg. QtCreator, CLion(awaik). For a wide range of other IDE cmake can generate the project files.

Example Workflow using QtCreator:

- Create a simple CMakeLists.txt, at least with the name of the project
- Load this into QtCreator
- Add source files, update the CMakeLists.txt from within QtCreator
- Build from within QtCreator, repeat

But the same `CMakeLists.txt` will be used to create the make file on command line. Or on your build server or CI system.